# The Euler class of any oriented sphere bundle would vanish?

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

I am reading chapter 11 of *Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology* by Bott & Tu. The argument in the following paragraph seems to imply that the Euler class of any oriented sphere bundle would vanish. I believe that it is wrong, since Example 11.18 gives a counterexample, but I don't know why. Can somebody help me find the error?

In the middle of page 119 of the book, the authors said that

> In sum, there is a global form that restricts to a generator on each fiber if and only if
>
> (a) $E$ is orientable, and
>
> (b) the Euler class $e(E)$ vanishes.

It can be concluded that if $E$ is any oriented sphere bundle and there is a global form that restricts to a generator on each fiber, then the Euler class $e(E)$ vanishes. But the global angular form constructed in page 121-122 really is a global form that restricts to a generator on each fiber. It can be constructed on any oriented sphere bundle. This implies that the Euler class of any oriented sphere bundle would vanish.

Comment: You should tell us what it says on page 119. To me I know this is incorrect because my definition of oriented sphere bundle requires the existence of such a globally defined form. And the Euler class is only defined for oriented sphere bundles.

Comment: Looking at the book, I believe they mistakenly write form when they mean closed form, i.e. if the Euler class vanishes the form comes from cohomology rather than just being a differential form that restricts to a closed form on each fiber.

Comment: @ConnorMalin  Thanks for your comment. I have made some changes to my question. But I did not fully understand your comment. Do you mean that the "global form" mentioned in the sentence I quoted should be a closed form, i.e. determine a cohomology class?

Comment: Yes this is my understanding. For example, if the sphere bundle is trivial this form will just be the class in cohomology coming from the dual of the fundamental class of the sphere (recall cohomology of the product is the tensor product of the cohomologies). The twisting of the fiber bundle then will sometimes mean that this global class is not a cocycle.

Comment: I have understood. Thanks for the insight.